# Excel VBA Importing text file into excel - Convert to Text

Tags: excel, vba, import

I have an Excel VBA to import from .CSV file.  It imports the data ok, but does not covert the columns to text.  I have large numbers and don't want to see the scientific format - 1.23E+08.
I need all 10 fields to be text regardless if alpha or numeric data.  I'm using Microsoft 365 for Enterprise.

This is what I have so far:

```
Sub ImportCSV()
'
' ImportCSV Macro
    'Imports a text file
    Dim vFileName


    On Error GoTo ErrorHandle

     vFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename()

    'If the user pressed "Cancel" or didn't select a text file,
    'exit the procedure.
    If vFileName = False Then
       GoTo BeforeExit
    End If


    Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=vFileName, _
        Origin:=xlMSDOS, StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:= _
        xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, Semicolon:=True, _
        Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar:="|", _
        TrailingMinusNumbers:=True, Local:=True, FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 2), Array(1, 2), Array(2, 2), Array(3, 2), _
                                    Array(4, 2), Array(5, 2), Array(6, 2), Array(7, 2), _
                                Array(8, 2), Array(9, 2))   
ErrorHandle:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume BeforeExit
End Sub
```

Like I said, the import works but not the changing formats.   I would appreciate any help.

I was expecting fields to be text.

Comment: See - https://superuser.com/questions/307496/how-can-i-set-excel-to-always-import-all-columns-of-csv-files-as-text#:~:text=Downside%3A%20Additionally%2C%20the,the%20source%20file  Apparently setting the field formats has no effect if the file extension is "CSV"   You can try using one of the approaches in that link.

Comment: I can import CSV with your code w/o any issue on Excel 365. All columns are in text format. There are two workaround solutions: 1. **QueryTables.Add** `https://rjsherman.com/vba/2014/import-txt-or-csv-file-into-excel-via-a-macro-querytable/`  2. **Power Query** (w/o VBA code)

Comment: Try adding `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Columns.AutoFit`

Answer (score 0):

You have to copy it in line by line.

```
Sub ImportCSV()

 Dim FSO As Object
 Dim TheFile As Object
 Dim aLines As Variant

 Dim Start As Range
 Dim CopyRange As Range
 
 Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 Set TheFile = FSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Temp\Test.csv", 1)
 
 aLines = Split(TheFile.ReadAll, vbLf)
 
 Set Start = Range("A1")
 
 For Each sLine In aLines
    
    TheCells = Split(Replace(Replace(sLine, " ", ""), vbCr, ""), ",")
    
    With Range(Start, Start.Offset(0, UBound(TheCells)))
        .NumberFormat = "@"
        .Value2 = TheCells
    End With
    
    Set Start = Start.Offset(1, 0)
    
 Next sLine

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not a VBA expert by any means.   On the line    "For Each sLine In aLine" I get a Run time Error '13'  Type Mismatch.

Comment: Fixed that last error - Not I get Run-Time -error 1004.    Application-defined or Object defined errors.

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?